# XML special characters in text node

Tags: xml, special-characters

I'm producing a XML file and need to know if I can have ' " characters in the text node of a XML element.

like:

```
<root>
   <location>48°51'24"N 2°21'03"E</location>
</root>
```

I've read: [w3c xml syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) and [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). And cannot figure out what applies to my situation.

If I validate this in a xml www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp it's valid. Do I need to convert this to `&apos;`? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can.
2. `&apos;` is valid here too, but not necessary. It would be necessary if you had `<location coords='48°51&apos;24"N 2°21'&apos;03"E'/>` to distinguish the apostrophes in text data from the apostrophes delimiting the attribute value.
3. Strictly you should use prime `′` and double-prime `″` for minutes and degrees of arch, single and double-quote is a kludge from the ASCII-only days. You can also use `&#x2032;` and `&#x2033` for those - no technical reason, it's just easier to type and won't choke if it passes through an ASCII-only system en route.